# Unrecognized command for AWS Secret creation with Docker - ECS deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, amazon-ecs

I'm planning to deploy a stack to ECS making use of the (new?) ["Deploying Docker containers on ECS"
feature](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/ecs-integration/). Though, I make use of GitLab for code versioning and CI/CD pipelines, therefore I want to store my Docker images in the GitLab registry (and they should be private).

I understand that ECS can easily support such a configuration through the `x-aws-pull_credentials` extension, therefore, following the link above, I make use of a GitLab access token and I try to create a Docker secret as suggested through the command

```
docker secret create gitLabAccessToken --username <GITLAB_USER>  --password <GITLAB_TOKEN>
```

Though, I get the error:

```
unknown flag: --username
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be with copy-pasting. Type the command directly.